# Stokes’s theorem and compact 2-manifolds in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, stokes-theorem, manifolds-with-boundary

I am trying to solve the following problem of Andrew Browder: "Mathematical Analysis; An Introduction" (Springer Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics):

Find **THE** compact $2$-manifold $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with area $\pi$ for which
$$
\int_{\partial M} {y^3dx + (3x - x^3)dy}
$$
is maximal.

The definition of Manifold in the book is:

[Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Gtol.png)

I have tried to use the Stokes’s theorem but I don't know how to find a such manifold $M$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The conditions in the definition of manifold can be simplified a lot when $k=n=2$.  Basically the author is looking for a smooth region in the plane.

Comment: I would call this a manifold with boundary, but perhaps his language is different. At any rate, you're looking for a closed region in the plane (with piecewise smooth boundary).

Answer (score 3):

Stokes' theorem gives you

$$\int_{\partial M}y^3dx+(3x-x^3)dy=\int_Md(y^3dx+(3x-x^3)dy)=3\int_M(1-(x^2+y^2))dxdy.$$

Since the integrand is positive iff $x^2+y^2\leq 1$, it appears that the integral will be maximal on $M=B(0,1)$ the ball of center $0$ and radius $1$.